# Stop automatic indentation and cursor movement while typing in major mode

Tags: indentation, major-mode

I've put together a [simple major mode](https://github.com/matthewrsilver/aql-mode) for syntax highlighting and indentation of [AQL](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/). This is my first, and I'm open to any suggestions there, but my question is more specific:

When I type two slashes to begin a comment, the moment I type the second slash the cursor jumps back to the beginning of the line, and the line is indented.

This even happens if I've already typed a bunch of code on the line. So if I have the following line (`^` is the cursor):

```
for u in users
              ^
```

and then I start to put a comment at the end of the line, the moment I type two slashes the cursor jumps:

```
for u in users \\
^
```

What's going on here? I've tried playing with and disabling `electric-indent-mode`, and I've tried manipulating `electric-indent-chars` but have not been able to alter this behavior in any way.

Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm found a workable solution Based on this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061453/in-emacs-how-to-disable-comment-auto-indent-in-c-c

I added the following to the mode's keymap (called `custom-map` below)

```
(define-key custom-map "/" 'self-insert-command)
(define-key custom-map "*" 'self-insert-command)
```

And all is resolved. Not sure if this is the *right* way, but it seems to work...